# SwiftUI BottomSheet Large White Screen and 'UIKit Internal bug: Unbalanced call to _endOcclusion'

Tags: swiftui, uikit, bottom-sheet

I’m using 2 different bottom sheets that the first one is showing up from my `ContentView -> LocationRequestIsOnView -> ItemInfoView`. ItemInfoView is my `bottom sheet`.

`LocationRequestIsOnView` has a MapKit for showing Annotations of Point Of Interests.

```
struct LocationRequestIsOnView: View {
@State private var selectedTabBarButton = ""
@Environment(\.requestReview) var requestReview

@Binding var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition
@Binding var searchResults: [MKMapItem]
@Binding var selectedResult: MKMapItem?
@Binding var route: MKRoute?
@Binding var visibleRegion: MKCoordinateRegion?
@Binding var isShowingBottomSheet: Bool
@StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()


var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        mapView
            .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
                NavigationLink(destination: SettingsView(isShowingBottomSheet: $isShowingBottomSheet)) {
                    poiButtons
                        .background(.thinMaterial)
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingBottomSheet) {
                if let selectedResult {
                    ItemInfoView(
                        isShowingBottomSheet: $isShowingBottomSheet,
                        route: $route,
                        selectedTabBarButton: selectedTabBarButton,
                        selectedResult: selectedResult,
                        url: self.shareLocation()
                    )
                    .presentationDetents([.medium, .fraction(0.12), .large])
                    .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled(upThrough: .medium))
                }
            }
            .onAppear(perform: {
                ReviewHandler.requestReview()
            })
            .onChange(of: searchResults) {
                if !searchResults.isEmpty {
                    let results = searchResults.map { $0.placemark.coordinate }
                    visibleRegion = calculateRegionToFit(coordinates: results)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedResult) {
                if let selectedResult {
                    getDirections()
                    if selectedResult.pointOfInterestCategory == .evCharger, let userLocation = locationManager.userLocation {
                        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userLocation, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.0291, longitudeDelta: 0.060))
                        visibleRegion = region
                        selectedTabBarButton = "EV"
                    } else {
                        if let userLocation = locationManager.userLocation {
                            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userLocation, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta:0.0291, longitudeDelta: 0.060))
                            visibleRegion = region
                            selectedTabBarButton = "Gas"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

var mapView: some View {
    Map(position: $cameraPosition, selection: $selectedResult) {
        ForEach(searchResults, id:\.self) {
            Marker(item: $0)
        }
        .annotationTitles(.hidden)
        
        UserAnnotation()
        
        if let route {
            MapPolyline(route)
                .stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 5)
        }
    }
}

var poiButtons: some View {
    HStack {
        Spacer()
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            POIButtons(
                searchResults: $searchResults,
                selectedTabBarButton: $selectedTabBarButton,
                isShowingBottomSheet: $isShowingBottomSheet
            )
            .padding(.top)
        }
        Spacer()
     }
   }
}

extension LocationRequestIsOnView {
 func getDirections() {
     route = nil
     isShowingBottomSheet = true
    
    if let userLocation = locationManager.userLocation {
        let coordinate = userLocation
        let request = MKDirections.Request()
        
        request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate))
        request.destination = selectedResult
         Task {
             let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
             let response = try? await directions.calculate()
             route = response?.routes.first
         }
      }
  }
}
```

`LocationRequestIsOnView` which works on same level with ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
 @StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()

 @State private var searchResults: [MKMapItem] = []
 @State private var selectedResult: MKMapItem?
 @State private var selectedTabBarButton = ""
 @State var isShowingBottomSheet = false
 @State private var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = .userLocation(followsHeading: true, fallback: .automatic)

var body: some View {
    if locationManager.state == .notDetermined { // User doesn't give location and their first time open the app
        LocationRequestView()
    } else { // User give location permission 
        LocationRequestIsOnView(
            cameraPosition: $cameraPosition,
            searchResults: $searchResults,
            selectedResult: $selectedResult,
            defaultSearchText: $defaultSearchText,
            isShowingBottomSheet: $isShowingBottomSheet
        )
    }
   }
 }
```

POIButtons behave like tabbar items but I don't use TabView().

```
struct POIButtons: View {
 @Binding var searchResults: [MKMapItem]
 @Binding var selectedTabBarButton: String
 @Binding var isShowingBottomSheet: Bool
 @Binding var defaultSearchText: String
 @StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager.shared
 @State var showSettingsView: Bool = false

 var body: some View {
    HStack {
        evStationButton
        gasStationButton
        NavigationStack {
            settingsButton
        }
    }
    .onAppear(perform: {
        if locationManager.state == .denied {
            search(for: defaultSearchText)
        }
    })
    .labelStyle(AdaptiveLabelStyle())
 }

 var evStationButton: some View {
    Button("EV Station", systemImage: "bolt.car") {
        search(for: "EV Charging Points")
        selectedTabBarButton = "EV"
        isShowingBottomSheet = false
        route = nil
    }
 }

 var gasStationButton: some View {
    Button("Gas Station", systemImage: "fuelpump.circle") {
        search(for: "Gas Station")
        selectedTabBarButton = "Gas"
        isShowingBottomSheet = false
        route = nil
    }
 }

 var settingsButton: some View {
    VStack {
        Button("Settings", systemImage: "gear.circle") {
            showSettingsView.toggle()
            selectedTabBarButton = "Settings"
            isShowingBottomSheet = false
            route = nil
        }
        .navigationDestination(
            isPresented: $showSettingsView) {
                SettingsView(isShowingBottomSheet: $isShowingBottomSheet)
            }
    }
 }

 func search(for query: String) {
    let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = query
    request.resultTypes = .pointOfInterest
    request.region = visibleRegion ?? MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: .userLocation,
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.008, longitudeDelta: 0.008))
    Task {
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        let response = try? await search.start ()
        searchResults = response?.mapItems ?? []
     }
   }
 }
```

When the user tap on an Annotation, ItemInfoView pops-up as a bottom sheet to be able to show details of the selected POI. The problem is exactly happening in this step. When the bottom sheet pops-up, I’m closing it through close icon button or using `.onDisappear` changing `isShowingBottomSheet` flag to false. As bottom sheet closing through .`onDisappear` it’s immediately shows a `large white view` and then closing. But the bottom sheet closing behavior is look good through close button xmark.circle.

```
struct ItemInfoView: View {
 @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
 @Binding var isShowingBottomSheet: Bool
 @Binding var route: MKRoute?

 var selectedTabBarButton = ""
 var selectedResult: MKMapItem

 var body: some View {
    if (isShowingBottomSheet) {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                HStack(spacing: 18) {
                    HStack {
                    ....
                    Button(action: {
                        isShowingBottomSheet = false
                        route = nil
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    }
                }
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    if selectedTabBarButton == "EV" {
                        Text("Electric Vehicle Charging Station")
                            .font(.system(size: 22))
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .frame(height: 36, alignment: .leading)
                    } else {
                        Text("Gas Station")
                            .font(.system(size: 22))
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .frame(height: 36, alignment: .leading)
                    }
                }
                     
                if selectedTabBarButton == "EV" {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                     ...
                }
                
                if selectedTabBarButton == "EV" {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                      ...
                }
        }
        .task {
            _ = Task {
                do {
                    try await ...
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            isShowingBottomSheet = true
        })
        .onDisappear(perform: {
            route = nil
            isShowingBottomSheet = false
         })
      }
    }
  }
```

In this point, I’m getting the following warning in Xcode log.
`UIKit Internal bug: Unbalanced call to _endOcclusion, please file a feedback report with any information you have that helps reproduce this bug!`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the pain point which is

> if let selectedResult

is getting nil just after closing the bottom sheet:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $isShowingBottomSheet) {
                ItemInfoView(
                    isShowingBottomSheet: $isShowingBottomSheet,
                    route: $route,
                    selectedTabBarButton: selectedTabBarButton,
                    selectedResult: selectedResult ?? MKMapItem(),
                    url: self.shareLocation()
                )
                .presentationDetents([.medium, .fraction(0.12), .large])
                .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled(upThrough: .medium))
            }
```

and adding else block for checking if the selectedResult is nil and dismiss bottom sheet

```
.onChange(of: selectedResult) {
        if let selectedResult {
            getDirections()
            if selectedResult.pointOfInterestCategory == .evCharger, let userLocation = locationManager.userLocation {
                let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userLocation, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.0291, longitudeDelta: 0.060))
                visibleRegion = region
                selectedTabBarButton = "EV"
            } else {
                if let userLocation = locationManager.userLocation {
                    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userLocation, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta:0.0291, longitudeDelta: 0.060))
                    visibleRegion = region
                    selectedTabBarButton = "Gas"
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            isShowingBottomSheet = false
        }
    }
```